# Cannot remove white input background in safari, css not applied

Tags: css, iphone, safari

I'm working on [this web application](https://baaygaan.com/en/ContactUs).
The client is testing it on an iPhone and sees white background behind the inputs. I don't have an iPhone, but I used [this emulator](https://appetize.io/demo?device=iphone8&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=13.7) and it shows white backgrounds too. I tried many tricks but still the white background is there. Also when I click on inputs, there is the blue outline around it, which shouldn't be there because I explicitly removed outline.

This is the style that I applied to my inputs. Any thoughts?

```
.contact-form .form-control, 
.contact-form .form-control:focus, 
.contact-form .form-control:focus-visible, 
.contact-form .form-control:focus-within, 
.contact-form .form-control:active, 
.contact-form .form-control:target, 
.contact-form .form-control:visited {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    appearance: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    background-clip: padding-box !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent,transparent) !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rob. As I read in the article you referred to, this isn't a MUST. And  there are so many css lines that affect a single element. It's hard to write them all inside the question, and would be even harder for the readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Safari on my windows (version 5.1.7 which is deprecated BTW), and saw the problem. Seems like some of the selectors are not supported in Safari, and therefore it doesn't load any of it.
So I removed **focus-visible**, **focus-within** and **target** selectors, and now it works as expected.